# How to show custom failure message in Specs2 (Scala)?

Tags: scala, matcher, specs2

For example, for code like this:

```
myNum must beEqualTo("SOME INTERESTING TEXT")
```

The message will be like the following:

```
java.lang.Exception: ArrayBuffer() doesn't have size 1 but size 0
```

Is there an elegant way to get customised message displayed here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you can name value you're testing.

```scala
myNum aka "meaningful name" must_== expectedValue
```

You can also overwrite the full message.

```scala
(myNum must_== expectedValue).setMessage("Full failure message")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for "mutable" expectations. See http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.ExpectationDescription.html for more options.

Comment: It is quite maddening that the above does not work for mutable expectations, and the link above does not work.  This one has no information on the matter: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.8.5/org.specs2.guide.ExpectationDescription.html

Comment: Sadly, `aka` worked, but not `setMessage`. It compiled, but it didn't changed the error message.

Comment: Looks like this `setMessage` sometimes does not work depending on the way you write your assertion: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/832